# How to detect RealSense cameras via C# WMI / WMI Code Creator

Tags: c#, wmi, realsense

I'm working on an application using C#.  I need to get all of the hardware information from the RealSense camera on the machine.

I was trying to figure out 'where' in the WMI Code Creator is the section that will output Intel RealSense cameras.  In particular, I need to find the hardware signature for the camera.

If there is another/better way to do this, please let me know.  I have to use C#, but I'm not required to use WMI.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SDK - depending on what properties you need https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/realsense/camera-sdk/v1.1/documentation/html/doc_mgsr300_writing_camera_specific_code.html

Comment: As near as I was able to tell when I looked at it yesterday, the SDK doesn't display the hardware signature.  I need the hardware signature so I can accurately find the cameras in the registry like you would see any hard drives, graphics cards etc.